# Download ArcGIS Map Tiles for larger areas

Tags: javascript, cordova, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I need to download map tiles for larger areas (mostly 100 km in radius).
Currently, I am using the offline tile library provided in Git Hub.
https://github.com/Esri/offline-editor-js.

The code used to calculate the number of tiles for each zoom level within the given extent is being stored in an JavaScript array and for a larger extent and zoom level the array becomes overwhelmed and crashes the app.

I have tweaked the code to store the tiles to be downloaded in indexedDB but I am concerned about the amount of data when the radius value increases.

What is the best way to achieve offline functionality in such case. I know about the tpk approach but looking for alternatives.

The app is packaged using cordova so it does not need to run on browser.

Any help is highly appreciated.